# Use of KeyListener with Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, keylistener

I want  to move  two objects at the same time.
I want to use Thread  for  this.   But it gives an error in the run method.
How can I do this?
How can I do this using keyboard events
Like 2-player games?

Here's the code:

```
public class First extends JPanel implements Runnable,KeyListener{
    int y1=303/2;
    private int vy=0;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(10,y1, 15, 20);
    }

    public void setVelocity(int v){
        vy=v;

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int keyCode=e.getKeyCode();
        if(keyCode==KeyEvent.VK_UP ){

        }
        if(keyCode==KeyEvent.VK_S){

        }

        else if(keyCode==KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){

        }
        else if(keyCode==KeyEvent.VK_W){

        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame jf=new JFrame();
        Panel p=new Panel();
        jf.add(p);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jf.setSize(300,300);
        jf.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }
}

class Second extends JPanel{
    int y2=303/2;
    private int vy=0;

    public void setVelocity(int v){
        vy=v;

    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g.fillRect(150,y2, 15, 20);
    }

}

class Panel extends JPanel{
    First f=new First ();
    Second s=new Second();
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        s.paintComponent(g);
        f.paintComponent(g);
    }
}
```

Comment: What error? post the stacktrace

Comment: The 'e' in the run method also throws an error

Comment: How can I move two objects using Thread?

Comment: You have to provide error messages/stack traces so people can figure out what's wrong.

Comment: This code does not compile. `e` is referenced in `run()` method but it's not available there. Do you keep last `KeyEvent` as a `First` class field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I do this using keyboard events Like 2-player games?

An event is only generated for the last key pressed, so basically you need to track all the keys pressed (and when they are released).

I've done this in the past using `Key Bindings` with a `Swing Timer`.

Check out the `KeyboardAnimation` example found in [Motion Using the Keyboard](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) for a working example of this approach.

The link will also explain what `Key Bindings` are and why they should be preferred over a KeyListener.